# true flat roof - insulation

Tags: insulation

Have 3 virtually flat roofs(1:12 and less) on structures that tie into main house. Remodeling under city permit. There is no room for blown. Ceiling joists are also roof rafters. Stuck on how to insulate. HELP!

Comment: What are the dimensions of the rafters? What is your target R-value?

Comment: This is a very vague question that feels like no effort went into before asking. As noted in one answer, there is a high quality source on ways to do this if one does an internet search. Unless you have a very specific question, this will likely get closed.

Answer (score 1):

There's a very standard method for this (you can even add more slope if they have drainage problems) which is to insulate the top of the roof with rigid foam sheets or spray foam.

By using tapered (wedge-shaped) sheets or appying more spray foam to low spots the slope can be changed.

Insulation can be above the waterproof membrane (not if changing slope is needed) or under a new waterproof membrane. If the surface is walked on there are cement/foam composite panels with a walkable top surface, but you'd need to make sure the structure will hold the weight of those as well as snow load, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If you search for `insulate flat roof` on google, this is the first thing that comes up:  [5 Ways to insulate a Flat Roof](https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/insulation/insulating-a-low-slope-shed-roof)

Short answer is you add insulation on top of the roof deck like polyiso panels or some combination of interior and exterior insulation.